# ocaml wrong pow function give correct output

Tags: ocaml, pow

i wrote a pow function in ocaml and by mistake a wrote this

```
let rec pow x y acc = if y = 1 then acc else pow x (y-1) x*x;;
```

this function can be called with any value of acc and output the correct answer, but this must output x^2 .

this is the correct functon :

```
let rec pow x y acc = if y = 0 then acc else pow x (y-1) x*acc;;
```

and call this function with the value of acc of 1.

my question is why first function give the correct output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that function application has higher precedence than binary operators. In the case at hand, the `else` term is equivalent to `(pow x (y-1) x) * x`, not `pow x (y-1) (x*x)`.